# In Powershell 5, what is the difference between "help" and "get-help"?

Tags: powershell

I'm relatively new to powershell, and I find the typesystem to be a little squishier than I would like.
This one has puzzled me, and confused me a few times now.

In this case, I was trying to list the available cmdlets, and avoid the cursed "..." truncation.

Help:

```bsh
PS C:\src\inst> help new-netipsecq* | format-table -AutoSize

Name                              Category  Module                    Synopsis
----                              --------  ------                    --------
New-NetIPsecQuickModeCryptoPro... Cmdlet    NetSecurity               New-NetIPsecQuickModeCryptoProposal...
New-NetIPsecQuickModeCryptoSet    Function  NetSecurity               ...
```

vs. Get-Help

```bsh
PS C:\src\inst> get-help new-netipsecq* | format-table -AutoSize

Name                                Category Module      Synopsis
----                                -------- ------      --------
New-NetIPsecQuickModeCryptoProposal Cmdlet   NetSecurity New-NetIPsecQuickModeCryptoProposa...
New-NetIPsecQuickModeCryptoSet      Function NetSecurity ...
```

So, with `get-member` we can see:

```bsh
PS C:\src\inst> help new-* | get-member
TypeName: System.String
Name             MemberType            Definition
----             ----------            ----------
```

vs. get-help

```bsh
PS C:\src\inst> get-help new-* | get-member
   TypeName: HelpInfoShort
Name          MemberType   Definition
----          ----------   ----------
```

Questions:

1. Why is `help` different than `get-help`?
   I've checked, `help` is *not* an alias.
2. Why does `help` return a string formatted to look like what `get-help` returns?

Hm...I found part of the answer myself.
I had tried `get-alias help` with no luck, but now I've stumbled on 'get-command'

```bsh
PS C:\src\inst> Get-Command help

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        help
```

3. Where does this function come from?

Comment: Try evaluating `$Function:help`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`help` is a built-in *function*** that is essentially **a wrapper around the `Get-Help` *cmdlet*** in order **to provide *interactive paging***.

- To discover the difference, use the [`Get-Command`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/) cmdlet: `Get-Command help` vs.
  `Get-Command Get-Help`
- To see the *body* of the `help` function, run `$function:help` or `Get-Content Function:help`

---

Behind the scenes, **the `help` function uses the [`Out-String`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/) cmdlet** in order to get the same representation that you would see in the PowerShell console, *as a string*, which is the prerequisite for using the **external `more.com` executable for paging (`less` on Unix)**, which only understands *string input* - and *not* the formatting *objects* that PowerShell - either implicitly or explicitly via `Format-*` cmdlets - uses for output formatting.

**`more.com` / `less` also *output* only *strings*** (and automatically disable paging when not outputting to a *terminal* (console), essentially passing the input string through), so **applying a `Format-*` cmdlet is pointless**, because it passes *strings* through as-is (only non-primitive *objects* are subject to formatting).

In other words, the  `| format-table -AutoSize` part of
`help new-netipsecq* | format-table -AutoSize` is a no-op.

However, **even with `Get-Help`, applying a `Format-*` cmdlet is pointless if you're unambiguously targeting a *single* topic**, because `Get-Help` *itself* provides proper output formatting for help topics.

Your sample commands use a *wildcard expression* (`new-netipsecq*`) to match *multiple* topics, which causes `Get-Help` to display a table *listing* those topics rather than rendering those topics themselves; such output *can* be meaningfully modified with `Format-*` cmdlets.

Note that this listing can even occur with a *literal* name, namely if there - unexpectedly - happen to be multiple conceptual topics *with the very same name* present. In that case, a workaround is needed to force rendering of those topics themselves - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55115076/45375).

Answer (score 1):

Answering 1 and 2:

This shows what is going on for why there is a difference...
`(get-command help).definition`

Help is like `get-help %* | more`

(Please, forgive the batch syntax!)